# Add parameter to widget build

Tags: flutter, dart

I work currently on a card , i want to add a parameter (int index) to the "Widget build" class, but i have an error (build is underlined in red) , but according to this link :https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate/build.html , is possible.

My code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cardProverb extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const cardProverb({
    @required this.text,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, int index) {//<-- Error here

    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),

      color: index % 2 == 0
          ? Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.4)
          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),

      elevation: 5,

      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.format_quote, size: 40),
            ),
            subtitle: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
                child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ]),

    );

  }
}
```

Comment: you should add `@required this.index` parameter to `const cardProverb({` constructor, not to `build` method

Comment: That documentation is for ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Declaring arguments you should do something like :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cardProverb extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final int index;

  const cardProverb({
    required this.text,  
    required this.index 
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {//<-- Error here

    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),

      color: this.index % 2 == 0
          ? Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.4)
          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),

      elevation: 5,

      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
            leading: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.format_quote, size: 40),
            ),
            subtitle: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
                child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ]),

    );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it to the constructor then you can use it wherever in this class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cardProverb extends StatelessWidget {
  late String text;
  late int index;

   cardProverb({
    required this.text,  required this.index
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      color: index % 2 == 0
          ? Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.4)
          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
      elevation: 5,
      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.format_quote, size: 40),
          ),
          subtitle: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
              child: Text(text, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare your index in class refer below code hope its help to you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      ),
      color: index % 2 == 0
          ? Colors.lightBlueAccent.withOpacity(0.4)
          : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.4),
      elevation: 5,
      child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          leading: Container(
            child: Icon(Icons.format_quote, size: 40),
          ),
          subtitle: Center(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 40, 0, 0),
              child: Text('text', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Your result screen-> [image]